# elixirLS debugger will not launch in vs code

Tags: elixir, elixirls

Installed elixirLS v0.17.2, elixir 1.15.7, Erlang/OPT 26. vs code 1.82.2.0.  elixirLS will not launch - ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in ElixirLS.Debugger.Server.launch/2.  Having issues with settings.json.  vs code says  "elixirLS.configuration": is an unknown configuration - here is a copy of the settings.json file
{
"elixirLS.envVariables": {},

```
"elixirLS.configuration":  {
    "elixirPath":  "C:\\Program Files\\Elixir\\bin",
    "elixirLS.projectDir": "C:\\Users\\Gordon\\servy"
}
```

}
Have no problem running elixir code from integrated terminal such as elixir lib/servy.ex. Correct output, etc. There seems to be some incompatibility between the elixirLS debugger and vs code.

Comment: On a similar setup but on a Mac I could not get elixirLS (using the elixir-tools plugin). I noticed in my process list a bunch of 'beam.smp' processes that were left running after elixirLS crashes. Killing those made everything start up again. Do you have any processes like that running even when vscode is stopped?

Comment: The elixir debugger does not launch but vs code is still operational.  I can switch to the python extension and run the python debugger.  Thanks for the feedback. - ideprize

Comment: It might not attempt to start elixirLS until you have the editor focused on an elixir file (.ex or .exs).  Once you do that is there anything in the OUTPUT tab by the terminal (you may have to change the drop down to the elixir plugin)

Comment: Before I start the debugger I have the .ex source in the editor.  It is beginning to look more and more like there is a communication issue between the ElixirLS debugger and the mix mix.exs build file.  The launch.json file is at the center of this especially the "task" spec.  Thanks for the feedback.  - ideprize